# Why is sort method part of Collections instead of AbstractList?

Tags: java, list, collections, conceptual

When sort method works upon only Lists, I feel keeping it in Collections class is somewhat buggy. Shouldn't there be a separate class  dedicated to Lists? Maybe AbstractList or something like ListUtil.. ?

Comment: `sort()` could be a method  of `List`.  Ex: `mylist.sort()` is possible in Groovy.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `Collection` and `Collections`?

Comment: Collections contains utilities for the whole collections framework, including Lists.  What's the issue with that?

Comment: A StackedList wont sort()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collections` is a helper class for all collections regardless of their type. In addition to method for the `List` there are methods specific to `Map`s, `SortedMap`s, `SortedSet`s, and, of course, `Collection`s.

Although making a separate helper for lists alone would be a justifiable choice, using a single helper class as a single place for all collection helpers makes perfect sense as well: it makes it easier for developers to remember where the methods are, because only one class is there.

Note that starting with Java-8 you can call `sort` as a [default method implementation on `List<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-), making the implementation even easier to locate.